# .Currentmember in a named set

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

I believe that due to the processing order of an analysis services script using context driven functions such as `currentmember` within a custom set is pointless i.e. the set is evaluated before the processor knows what the `currentmember` actually is.

Are there any exceptions to the above rule? i.e. what is an example of using the `currentmember` function within a custom set?

Comment: The Generate function will iterate over the 1st argument (a set); if the expression you use on the 2nd arg refers to .currentMember it uses each of the elements of the set as currentMember.

Comment: @nsousa thanks - the exception to the rule! scope changes once within `Generate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by "within a custom set", `Currentmember` may have its uses. I assume here you meant the usage in the definition expression of the set.

Query level sets take into account the WHERE condition, which may set one or more `CurrentMembers`.
Cube level named sets may be defined as `dynamic` since version 2008, hence the same behavior is true.

While you can use `CurrentMember` in the iteration over a set that `Filter` and `Generate` do, you can also use a set alias and the `Current` property, which I find more clear:

```
Generate([Customer].[Country].[Country].Members as c,
         c.Current.Name,
         ', '
        )
```

or

```
Filter([Customer].[Country].[Country].Members as c, 
       InStr(c.Current.Name, 'a') > 0
      )
```

which could have been written

```
Generate([Customer].[Country].[Country].Members,
         [Customer].[Country].CurrentMember.Name,
         ', '
        )
```

and

```
Filter([Customer].[Country].[Country].Members,
       InStr([Customer].[Country].CurrentMember.Name, 'a') > 0
      )
```

as well.

Please note that the second case does not deal with the usage of `CurrentMember` in the definiton of the set that you iterate over, but in the definition of the String or set that results from the `Generate` or `Filter` expression.

Comment: +1 thanks Frank. Any possible loss of performance when using set aliases such as `as c`?

Comment: @whytheq I do not think so. Maybe it is even faster.